# Is dF/dr the same GradF?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

Consider the line integrals

$$\int f\nabla g \, ds + \int g\nabla f \, ds $$ which I can rewrite as

$$\int (f\nabla g \ +g\nabla f) \,ds $$ This seems a lot like a product rule and I would like to say that

$$\int (f\nabla g \ +g\nabla f) \,ds = \int \frac{d}{ds} (fg) \, ds  $$ If this is true then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, this is simply equal to fg.

However is it true that $$\frac{d}{ds} (fg) = (f\nabla g \ +g\nabla f) $$

in this case ds is like $d\vec r$ and so this comes back to saying is

$$\nabla F= \frac{d}{d\vec r}F$$

This is an attempt to prove theoretically:

[image]

Comment: Wiki says $\nabla f=df^T$... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient How do you define $df/d\vec r$?

Answer (score 1):

Though $\frac{d}{d\vec r}$ doesn't have much meaning unless it's just another way of writing $\nabla$, your more precise statement is true. You can also replace $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$. All you need is the gradient product rule

$$ \vec\nabla(fg) = f \vec\nabla g + g \vec\nabla f $$

and the multi-variable chain rule

$$ \frac{d}{dt} f(\vec c(t)) = (\vec\nabla f)(\vec c(t)) \cdot \vec c'(t) $$

The gradient product rule is proved easily with the definition of the gradient and familiar one-dimensional product rule:

$$ \begin{align*} \vec\nabla(fg) &= \frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x} \hat\imath  + \frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial y} \hat\jmath + \frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial z} \hat k \\
&= \left(f \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + g \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \hat\imath + \left(f \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + g \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \hat\jmath + \left(f \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} + g \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right) \\
&= f\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \hat\imath + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \hat\jmath + \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\right) + g\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat\imath + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \hat\jmath + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right) \\
&= f \vec\nabla g + g \vec\nabla f
\end{align*} $$